# Error in Visual srudio code java extension: Set other project in source path: The source path must be contained in the project root folder

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Suppose I have 4 independent Java projects: project0, project1, project2, and project3.

Inside each project, I have the src folder, and inside some packages and classes. Project 1, 2, and 3 use classes from project0.

In Eclipse, I can indicate in a section that the sources of project 0 are used.
When I try something similar in VScode, I go to configure the classpath of project one and see that it includes its src folder. When I add the src folder of project0, I get the following error: "The source path must be contained in the project root folder."

I can solve this by creating the .jar of project 0 and adding it to the other projects, but this is very inconvenient when making quick tests.

I know there are tools like Maven or Ant to do these things, but I would like to know if there is any way to indicate in vscode that one project uses classes from another without having to include the .jar as a dependency.

```
projeca0
-src
 -package0
   -class0

peoject1
 -src
 -package1
  -class1
```

If class1 uses class0, it will fail. I wish add project0/src as dependency of project1 without creatinfg project0 .jar and add it to project 1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry about my english, i just rewrite the quetion

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the same question as a Github Issue (here)[https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2853]

As they said: "Is not posible support referencing another unmanaged folder as a dependency today"

Vs code calls unmanaged folder any without build tools, so for the moment the only option is to inject dependency as a .jar file

Answer (score 0):

Copying `class0` to `project1` is a simple and effective way. Or add `project0` to `project1's` source path.

[image]

Comment: I did add folder to source path but doesent work. I open a github issue to ask: [this issue](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2853), and they say it is not possible for the moment. You need to do a jar file or use a build tool. They marked the issue as enhancement